# Matching info in a file

Tags: ruby

I want to write some code to do the things below:

- If the input file (e.g.: `"file.out"`) contains the info like `"n failures, n errors"`, `"n failures, 0 errors"`, or `"0 failures, n errors"` (where `n >= 1`), then `puts "script failed"` (because there are failures or errors displayed).
- If the input file contains the info: `"0 failures, 0 errors"`, then `puts "script passed"` (because there are no failures and errors displayed).

I think I need to write something like below (but it does not work correctly as the scenario I expect):

```
if open("#{file}.out").grep(/[1-9][0-9]* failures|[1-9][0-9]* errors/).length > 0
   puts "script passed"
else
   puts "script failed"
end
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def check_script file
  open(file) do |io|
    io.read =~ /(\d+)\s+failures,\s+(\d+)\s+errors/
    puts "script #{$1 == "0" && $2 == "0" ? "passed" : "failed"}"
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
check_script("file.out")
```

Comment: this solution works well when my file including the info like: 0 failures, **1** errors (in this case, system returns "script failed" as expected). However, when my file includes the info: 0 failures, **2** errors, system returns "script passed, but I expect script will return "script failed".

Comment: Also, when my script has info: "0 failures, 0 errors", system returns "script failed", but I expect the returned info is "script passed".

Comment: @battleship Are you sure that the file does not include `0 failures, 0 errors` somewhere in addition to `0 failures, 2 errors`? I doubt that you have what you say you have.

Comment: it was my mistake, I was pointing to a wrong file in incorrect location. And now I'm very happy that your suggested code works perfect. Thanks much for your guide.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming file contain

```
info: 0 failures, 0 errors
```

code will be

```
(File.open("#{file}.out").read).scan(/info: ([0-9]+) failures, ([0-9]+) errors/) do |failures, errors|
    puts (failures.to_i > 0 || errors.to_i > 0) ? "script failed" : "script passed"
end
```

Comment: This solution also works well for my scenario. Thanks so much for your great answer.